# XPages events onStart and onComplete in conjunction with dojo.connect

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I would like to use `xp:eventHandler` events `onStart` and `onComplete` in conjunction with `dojo.connect`.

*Take a look at this code snippet:*

```
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("#{id:btnSubmit}"), "onclick", callbackOnClick);
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("#{id:btnSubmit}"), "onComplete", callbackOnComplete);

function callbackOnClick() {
    alert("onclick works!!!");
}

function callbackOnComplete() {
    alert("onComplete works!!!");
}   ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>

  <xp:button value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:// do something on server side}]]></xp:this.action>
<!--            <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("oncomplete");]]></xp:this.onComplete>-->
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

`dojo.connect` works perfect for `onclick`-Event but it doesn't work for `onComplete`-Event?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `onclick` is a real browser event (which can be connected with dojo), the `oncomplete` event is provided by the XSP object of XPages only.

When looking into the generated HTML code (uncommented out the onComplete event of your example), you can see it's code converted to a string (second to the last parameter):

```
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2", "view:_id1:btnSubmit", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "@none", null, "alert\u0028\u0022oncomplete\u0022\u0029;", null);
```

This string is evaluated when the *XSP._partialRefresh* method is finished.

That's why you can't use `dojo.connect` here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see why you need to use dojo.connect to attach the functions to the onclick and to the onComplete events.

Just put the functions **callbackOnClick** and **callbackOnComplete** in the **xp:eventHandler** corresponding methods.